# How do I allow access to a variable in one class to another without using 'static' or passing it as a parameter?

Tags: c#, game-engine, sfml

I always have a lot of problems using static variables, so I want to avoid it.

I am making a game using SFML.net and C#, and wish to load all the textures during the Game's Initialize method. Then when a Character is created, I want the Character to do something simple like...

```
Image IdleAnimation = Game.IdleAnimation1;
```

Here are the classes involved: main.cs, Game.cs & Init.cs

-

main.cs

```
static class main
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.Run();
    }
}
```

-

Game.cs

```
 public partial class Game
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Init();
```

-

Init.cs

```
public partial class Game
{
    public Image IdleAnimation { get; set; }

    private void Init()
    {
        IdleAnimation = new Image("Filepath\\filepath\\filpath");
    }
```

-

```
class Character : IGameObject
{
    Image CharacterIdleAnimation;

    public Character()
    {
       CharacterIdleAnimation = Game.IdleAnimation;
    }
```

But I get the error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Game.IdleAnimation.get'

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want your classes to have an explicit reference to a `Game` instance, you have to make the instance available in some other way.  For instance:

```
public static class main
{
    public static Game game;

    public static void Main()
    {
        game = new Game();
        game.Run();
    }
}
```

Now you can reference the current `Game` instance via `main.game`.

Alternatively it might be useful to define the entire `Game` class as static, unless you have a specific reason not to.  If there is only going to be a single instance of the `Game` class then there's no pressing need *not* to have it static.

In the case where you have multiple instances, I would prefer to pass required information by interface reference in the method calls or by reference to the constructor so it can be saved in the object's state.

Comment: oh dur! Of course! This would have fixed everything too... Now I understand why I wasnt able to use game.variable

Answer (score 1):

This line of code will refer to the `Game` class (notice the uppercase 'G'):

```
Game.IdleAnimation1;
```

This line of code will refer to the `game` variable (notice the lowercase 'g'):

```
Game game = new Game();
```

Since your property `IdleAnimation` is not `static`, you will have to access it trough an instance of type `Game`, e.g. `game`.

That's the cause of your error. It's hard to provide a solution as well because you don't specify what it is you want to reach. If you will be reusing `IdleAnimation` a lot and it will never change, then it might actually make sense to hold it as `static`.

Comment: Yes, it will never ever change. All images loaded at first, will never be edited. They will however be copied to a non-static new image. I just read alot around here to "always avoid using static variables because they're evil"

Comment: If it never ever, pinky swear, ever will change then you can make it `static` (or at least: if it has to be consistent between all instances). You might want to explore other options as well to see if you can't just define it somewhere more suitable, but that's further design that you'll have to look into.

Comment: Thank you. It works fine as static. I guess when I get errors because of it, I will work through those. I just figured all the problems ive had messing with static variables was because of the general hate around this site about static variables, as if they are ALWAYS bad practice.

Comment: `static` variables are dangerous, but I wouldn't call them evil. They will be perceived as evil if people abuse them though. Make sure you only use them when it's appropriate. It seems weird to have it on a class called `Game`, though. Maybe all these animations would be better off if grouped together in a class that does just that: provide animations?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you basically can't get arount that without a static class or field.
You need it to access your animation from everywhere.

**But** that's not really that bad in this case, because you load the animation *once* and don't change it.
As long as you don't change your static properties or fields, you won't run into that many problems.

I would prefer to make a `static class` containing your animations.

```
public static class Animations
{
    public static Image IdleAnimation = new Image("FilePath");
}
```

Now you can reference the animation where ever you want:

```
public class Character
{
    public Image CharacterIdleAnimation { get; private set; }

    public Character()
    {
        this.CharacterIdleAnimation = Animations.IdleAnimation;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I just ended up doing. Thank you!

Comment: character.S_Idle = GameGraphics.S_Idle;

It works! :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe everyone that programs for passion has attempted to make a game at one point in their life or another.  Because of that, the beautiful thing about creating a game is that while the creative part is all you, a lot of the nuance has been solved in very creative, flexible, and useful ways.  Many [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) actually directly correlate to game development. Particularly useful in your case is either the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) or [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Singleton:

```
public partial class Game
{
    public static Game Instance { get; set; }
    public Image IdleAnimation { get; set; }

    static Game() {
        Game.Instance = new Game();
        Game.Instance.Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        IdleAnimation = new Image("Filepath\\filepath\\filpath");
    }
    ...
}

class Character : IGameObject
{
    Image CharacterIdleAnimation;

    public Character()
    {
       CharacterIdleAnimation = Game.Instance.IdleAnimation;
    }
    ...
}
```

Or, Dependency Injection (DI):

```
public interface IGame
{
    public Image IdleAnimation { get; set; }
    public void Init();
}

public partial class Game : IGame
{
    public Image IdleAnimation { get; set; }

    private void Init()
    {
        IdleAnimation = new Image("Filepath\\filepath\\filpath");
    }
    ...
}

class Character : IGameObject
{
    Image CharacterIdleAnimation;

    public Character(IGame game)
    {
       CharacterIdleAnimation = game.IdleAnimation;
    }
    ...
}
```

You can use a variety of pre-canned Inversion of Control (IoC)/DI (not the same, but many people use the interchangeably) frameworks to fill in the games.  Two very popular open source options are Ninject and StructureMap.  I've used both with great success... in my opinion Ninject is more user friendly, but StructureMap is more performant.  Unity is Microsoft's entry, but I'm not personally fond of it.  The nice thing about DI frameworks is that only the initial bootstrapping/configuration is "difficult," everything else is simple afterwards.